# Regular expression for phone number in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter and I want to check user input with regular expression for phone number. My pattern is [+]zero or one and [0-9] number.
Following format,
+959250142935
09250142935
This is my pattern - /\+?[0-9]$/
This does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern to check for valid phone number. There is a additional `{5,}` to set a minimum length of the phone number (in this case 5), so the phone number can't be a single number:

`^[\+]{0,1}[0-9]{5,}$` or `^[\+]{0,1}\d{5,}$`

You can use this pattern directly on the `<input>`:

```
<input pattern="^[\+]{0,1}[0-9]{5,}$" type="text"/>
<input pattern="^[\+]{0,1}\d{5,}$" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex

`/^(\+|0|1)\d+$/`

If the number must be certaing length

`/^(\+|0|1)\d{10}$/`